# Java Regex: Match a character followed by whitespace?

Tags: java, regex

This is driving me nuts... I have an input string like so:

```
String input = "T ";
```

And I'm trying to match and replace the string with something like so:

```
String output = input.replace("T\\s", "argggghhh");
System.out.println(output);  // expected: "argggghhh"
                             // actual: "T "
```

What am I doing wrong?  **Why won't the `\\s` match the space?**

Keep in mind I want to match multiple white space characters (`\\s+`), but I can't get this simple case to work :(.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `replaceAll()` instead of `replace()`.

`replace()` does **not** use regular expressions.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence) vs. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)